# Master/Detail Android flow not working in tablet emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, master-detail

I have created a master/detail app in Android Studio using all of the defaults:

- File | New Project
- Give the application a name and domain
- Choose phone and tablet, minimum SDK API 14
- Master/Detail flow
- Object kind: item and items

I have created a tablet emulator:

- Click on AVD manager
- Click on create virtual device
- click on tablet
- click on Nexus 10, click on next
- select an API 21 x86 system image
- click on Show advanced settings
- reduce the RAM to b768
- confirm that Use Host GPU is checked.
- Click on finish.

I had previously enabled HAXM, as evidenced from the output from "sc query intelhaxm" in a command window:

```
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                        (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

When I run my application and send it to the emulator, it displays as if it was on a cell phone.  Here is a picture of the screen: https://app.box.com/s/f4p5nmbstdr3iwxqtaszqq8jwru8mu2d.  Note that the master entries have lines that go all the way across the screen, rather than just part way.

I also run the application on my connected Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.  Here is a picture of the app on that device: https://app.box.com/s/gye4f87aqlt9s5cc3es1iq6r6dk9ozot.  Note that the master lines only go part of the way to the right, and that the first master item's detail is visible on the right.

It would appear that my problem is that my emulator is not truly emulating a tablet, and instead is emulating a phone.  Why is that and how can I fix it?

I'm running Windows 8.1 and Android Studio 1.0.1

Answer (score 4):

A quick workaround for me was running it in a different emulator. **10.1" WXGA (Tablet) landscape** worked.